# What's the longest sentence you can make using only 2-letter words?

Tags: wordplay, english, language

The sentence has to be grammatically correct, and probably shouldn't be too nonsensical.  Here are a few examples:

> Is he in on it?
>
> Is it to be me?
>
> Ma, Ed is in my gi!

*Note:  This puzzle will obviously have multiple answers, and the current "winner" will be unseated again & again over time.  I hope that's okay on this site!*

Comment: Good candidate for an [`open-ended`](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/open-ended) tag

Comment: Ты не на юг ли? - you never said it has to be in English. Btw, it's harder in Russian, longer words in general. Also, Не яд, но щи не ем.

Comment: It seems fairly clear that these can be extended more or less ad lib using constructions like "A or B or C or D", strings of musical notes, etc. I think I've got to agree that this is Too Broad, though it's a borderline case.

Comment: I think this could be improved by only allowing whole, grammatically correct words, no names, no acronyms. And the sentece should actually make sense (i.e. something which could be said/written in real life by a real person). If this makes the challenge too hard, maybe graduate to three letter words instead of two

Answer (score 2):

Oh, hi Mr. Ed, is it ok to go to my ma Li or no?

Answer (score 2):

Planning and organizing an unusual bovine activity...

Oh hi Jo is it OK if we do an ox op?-is it to be:me to do an ox op in LA in AM,Al to do an ox op in MO in PM,or is it to be:me to do an ox op in LA in PM,Al to do an ox op in MO in AM,or is it to be:me to do an ox op in MO in PM,Al to do an ox op in LA in AM,or is it to be:me to do an ox op in MO in AM,Al to do an ox op in LA in PM?-as if it is to go,it is up to us to do it:it is up to me if Bi Ed is OK,or if he is no go to it,it is up to Al to no go it if Bi Ed is No,so we do it OK or is it an Oh no? Mo...

Answer (score 1):

Without some rules, there is no limit.

> Is do,re,mi,fa,so,la,ti,do ok, or is re,mi,fa,so,ti,do,la ok or is ti to so ok or fa to do ok ...

Or maybe a little more interesting.

> If it is ok if he do it to it in LA, he do it to me in LA if we do to it in LA, or it do it to me if he do it to it or me in LA.

Answer (score 0):

> It is up to me to be an ad in my gi, to be an ox in my gi, or to ax my gi.

Not particularly pretty, but means "It's my responsibility to either advertise something while wearing my gi, be clumsy while wearing my gi, or destroy my gi completely."

Answer (score 0):

If it is to be,it is up to me to do it.
Or if it is to go,it is up to me to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Mm, if he is to be in on an op, he is to be at an ag in the am to ax an ox,

Answer (score 0):

Do we go "do re me" or is it "do re me fa so la ti" as no "fa so la ti" is so la-de-da.